# My id links are not working but I dont know why

Tags: html

1. Id links are not working when I click on one of them its navigate me to wrong heading or top of the webpage but not to that heading.
   Example: When I click on link "#headingClimbing" its navigate me to heading with id "headingLead"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#headingClimbing" class="a1">Climbing</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#headingLead" class="a2">Lead</a>
  <h1 id="headingClimbing">Climbing</h1>
  <h1 id="headingLead">Lead</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: According to your code, it *should* take you to those sections. Keep in mind that your code example doesn't include enough body content to separate out the headings. Depending on the rest of your content, there may be a JavaScript error or similar interfering.

Comment: I've used just HTML and CSS. Maybe it's something with browser?

Comment: It is not the Browser. as @ObsidianAge mentions, you do not have enough content around each heading so the page cannot `scroll you to the actual section`